# Laravel 5.8 query to get count on polymorphic relationships

Tags: eloquent, polymorphism, laravel-5.8

I have the following tables where 1 page has many containables, and each containable has either lines or questions:

```
// Page model
class Page extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = ['title'];
 
   public function containables() {
     return $this->morphMany(Containable::class, 'containable');
   }
}

Example pages table data: 

| id | title  |
|----|--------|
| 1  | Page 1 |
```

```
// Containable model
class Containable extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'containables';

   protected $fillable = ['containable_id', 'containable_type'];

   public function containable() {
       return $this->morphTo('containable');
   }

   public function sequences() {
      return $this->hasMany(ContainableSequence::class, 'containable_id', 'id');
}

Example containables table data:
 
| id | containable_id | containable_type |
|----|----------------|------------------|
| 2  | 1              | App\Page         |
| 3  | 1              | App\Page         |
```

```
// ContainableSequence model
class ContainableSequence extends Model
{
   protected $table = 'containable_sequence';

   protected $fillable = ['containable_id', 'sequencable_id',  
                          'sequencable_type', 'order'];

   public function sequencable() {
        return $this->morphTo('sequencable');
   }
   
}

Example containable_sequence table data:

| id | containable_id | sequencable_type | sequencable_id | order |
|----|----------------|------------------|----------------|-------|
| 4  | 2              | App\Line         | 6              | 1     |
| 5  | 2              | App\Question     | 8              | 2     |
| 6  | 3              | App\Question     | 9              | 1     |
| 7  | 3              | App\Line         | 7              | 2     |
```

```
// Line model
class Line extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'lines';

  protected $fillable = ['name'];
}

Example Lines table data:

| id | name   |
|----|--------|
| 6  | line 1 |
| 7  | line 2 |
```

```
// Question model
class Question extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'questions';

  protected $fillable = ['name', 'marks'];
}

Example Questions table data:
| id | name       | marks |
|----|------------|-------|
| 8  | Question 1 | 10    |
| 9  | Question 2 | 15    |
```

I am trying to perform a join the tables with polymorphic associations to get the count of line(s) and question(s) linked to a page.

Starting from a page, how can I get the counts of related lines and questions using eloquent?  Thanks

Comment: Can you post your model definitions in your post?

Comment: I added the class definitions